# Printing a sentence, only if a Makefile rule is executed

Tags: c, makefile, printing, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I am customizing my Makefile for a school project.

I would like to print the following sentence but only when the .c files from my SRCS_DIR have been actually compiled.

> All the .c files have been compiled successfully !

If I move the printf that you see in line 3 of the code block below to the last line, it prints the message after each .c file being compiled...
Thus, I created a COMPILED variable which I set to 0 at the beginning of my Makefile, and then I change its value to 1 during compilation (line 11 in the code block below). I tried to use the ifeq condition (line 2 in the code block below), but the sentence does not print when I do that.

```
$(NAME): $(LIBFT_AR) $(OBJS)
ifeq ($(COMPILED), 1)
    printf "$(GREEN)> All the .c files have been compiled successfully !$(END)\n"
endif
    printf "$(BLUE)> Creating the executable file :$(END) $@\n"
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_AR) -lreadline -o $(NAME)
    printf "$(GREEN)> Executable file has been created successfully !$(END)\n"

$(OBJS_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR)/, $(SUBDIRS_LST))

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)/%.c $(INCS) Makefile | $(OBJS_DIR)
override COMPILED=1
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCS_DIR) -c $< -o $@
    printf "$(BLUE)> Compiling :$(END) $<\n"
```

Do you have any explanation regarding this issue and/or a solution that could help me to solve the problem ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefiles are not scripting languages.  Make doesn't read the makefile and run each rule as it's read.  Make will (1) parse the entire makefile (and any included files) and build an internal graph of all the prerequisites, than (2) run recipes for targets that are outdated.  Content that is NOT IN A RECIPE is always evaluated during the first step.  Content that IS IN A RECIPE is always evaluated during the second step.

Lines that are *not* indented with TABs, are *not* in recipes (and so are evaluated during the first step).  Lines that *are* indented with TABs, are in recipes (and so are evaluated--which means, given to the shell to execute--during the second step).

Maybe you can now see why your attempts cannot work: the if-statements and variable assignment of `COMPILED` are always evaluated, during the first step, before make has decided whether or not any targets should be built.

I'm not really sure I understand your goal.  If the recipe of your executable is being invoked then it means that all your source files have been compiled: that's what a makefile *does*.  Maybe you are trying to make a distinction between a build where at least one source file was compiled, and a build where no source files had to be recompiled but the target (the executable) was out of date?

If that's what you want the simple way to solve your problem is with automatic variables; for example the [`$?` automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_003f) expands to the list of prerequisites that were out of date.  You can do something like:

```
$(NAME): $(LIBFT_AR) $(OBJS)
        test -z '$(filter %.o,$?)' || printf "$(GREEN)> All the .c files have been compiled successfully !$(END)\n"
        printf "$(BLUE)> Creating the executable file :$(END) $@\n"
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT_AR) -lreadline -o $(NAME)
        printf "$(GREEN)> Executable file has been created successfully !$(END)\n"
```

The [`$(filter ...)` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter) will expand to the list of `.o` files in the `$?` variable; if that's empty then no `.o` files were rebuilt.

Comment: Oh okay! Now I understand why it didn't work the way I wrote it... Thank you !
Yes, my goal is to make a distinction between : 1) a build where a source file has been modified (and thus, recompiled) 2) a build where only source files from my personal library has been recompiled (by another Makefile, I use recursive make). I tried your cmd line, but unfortunately if I modify a .c file in my personal library, I get the following error `make: *** [minishell] Error 1`. But thanks a lot, I'll try few things with the test command and hopefully find something that will do the trick :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot one of my own cardinal rules (prefer `||` to `&&` when writing make recipes).  I updated the example and it should work now.

Comment: Just a note, you probably should be using single-quotes around your `printf` lines not double quotes, just to be safe.

Comment: You're right, it works perfectly, and I understand even better how the makefile behaves thanks to your tip. Thanks a lot !!!